# CsvHelper. How can i invoke ConvertUsing of MemberMap in an extension method?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

While trying to extend the [MemberMap](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/MemberMap%602/) of CsvHelper

```
        public static MemberMap Required<T>(this MemberMap map, string columnName)
        {
            return map.Name(columnName).ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetField(columnName)))
                    throw new CsvParserException($"{columnName} is required");
                return row.GetField<T>(columnName);
            });
        }
```

i get the error

> 'MemberMap' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertUsing' and no accessible extension method
>        'ConvertUsing' accepting a first argument of type 'MemberMap' could be found

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Only the generic version of MemberMap has the ConvertUsing method. You're using the non-generic version: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/MemberMap

Comment: @steve16351 That's great, thank you. But, how can i use the generic version from an extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to `<TClass, T>` made it magic.

```
public static MemberMap Required<TClass, T>(this MemberMap<TClass, T> map, string columnName)
        {
            return map.ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetField(columnName)))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{columnName} is required, but missing from row {row.Context.Row}");
                return row.GetField<T>(columnName);
            });
        }
```

Special thanks to Steve.